# Django "if" condition with context_processors variable

Tags: python, html, django

I'm creating some themes for my `Django` website and I would like to modify the HTML text color in function of `context_processors variable`.

The context_processors variable is : **Datasystems** or **Cameroun** (I have two themes up to now, but I will have maybe 4 or 5 themes at the end).

So, if the variable is Datasystems, text' color should be blue. If the variable is Cameroun, text' color should be green.

My context_processors.py (it works perfectly) file looks like :

```
from django.conf import settings
from Configurations.models import Theme

def GetTheme(request):
    return {'mytheme' : Theme.objects.values_list('favorite_theme').last()[0].encode("ascii")}
```

My HTML template looks like :

```
{% extends 'Base_Accueil.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

        <p align="center"><img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}"></p>

        {% if {% get_static_prefix %}{{ mytheme }} == "Datasystems" %}
        <h2 align="center"> <font color="#0083A2"> Bienvenue sur la page d'accueil du logiciel DatasystemsEC</font></align></h2>
        <p></p>

        {% if {% get_static_prefix %}{{ mytheme }} == "Cameroun" %}
        <h2 align="center"> <font color="#007A5E"> Bienvenue sur la page d'accueil du logiciel DatasystemsEC</font></align></h2>
        <p></p>

        {% endif %}

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h3 align="center"> <font color="#0083A2"> Vous êtes connecté(e) en tant que {{ user.username }} </font></align></h3>
        {% endif %}


{% endblock content %}
```

How I can execute this `if` condition ?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use `get_static_prefix` in there. And anyway, didn't I answer this question for you a few days ago?

Comment: It looks like you might want `{% if mytheme == "Datasystems" %}`, but I don't understand why you are trying to include `{% get_static_prefix %}` inside the if statement.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I thought I have to write `get_static_prefix` before to call my context_processors variable. I didn't read very well the documentation about this. You're right, maybe one week, but the context is a bit different. I'm not adding this variable to a path with `href` but with `if` statement. Sorry if it's a duplicate from your point of view

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you for your answer ! If I call a variable, why, in this case, I don't have to put `{{ }}` around `mytheme` ?

Comment: That's just the way the Django template language works. You don't need to include `{{ }}` to reference a variable inside a template tag.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thank you for the explanation !

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
{% if mytheme == "Datasystems" %}
```

or better, use:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link type="stylesheet" href="themes/{% static mytheme %}.css" />
```

to load `statis/themes/Datasystems.css` and do all your styling over there.